# Exported shapefile from ArcGIS won't open in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I exported a shapefile from ArcGIS and wanted to load it into QGIS. However, the following error occurs:

*Invalid Data Source: /Users/Desktop/Documents/merged_buffer.shp is not a valid or recognized data source.*

When I check the files in the folder, the icons to the left seem white. The other shapefiles have a black icon, originate from QGIS itself and can be loaded correctly. What is the problem here?

[image]

Comment: Do they open correctly when you re-import them in ArcGIS?

Comment: Why buffer in Arc and load into QGIS? Also, if you're able to load the other files, simply merge again using QGIS.

Comment: @MrXsquared Yes they do

Comment: @Erik I performed some actions with ArcGIS that were difficult to do in QGIS. The merged buffer is the result of these edited separate buffers, so the end result won't be the same.

Comment: You might run a repair geometry on your shapefile before trying to add it to QGIS.